# Find whether the following set is countable/uncountable

Tags: set-theory

Find whether the following sets are countable or uncountable:
1. The set of all functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$.
2. The set of all functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to  $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Suppose the set were just $\{1,2\}$...could you solve it then?

Comment: @lulu For {1,2,3} to $\mathbb{Z}$, I think it will be countable, all the functions will be a triplet $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ , $z_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is countable in a way similar to why set of fractions is countable. But what about the 1st part of the question? Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the diagonal argument. Suppose the set of all functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$ is countable. You can list them as $f_1,f_2,f_3,\cdots$ Then define a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\{1,2,3\}$ which is not in the list, implying that the set is in fact uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

The first one should be uncountable:

Consider the power set $\mathcal{P}(Z)$, which is uncountable. for each element $S \in \mathcal{P}(Z)$, we have the characteristic function $\chi_{S}$, now we define $f=\chi_{S}+1$, which will give a value of 1 or 2. So we get uncountably many such $f$.

So the first one should be uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

1. The set of all functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\{1,2,3\}: \{1,2,3\}^\mathbb{Z}$
   $$|\{1,2,3\}^\mathbb{Z}|=3^{\aleph_0}=\aleph$$
2. The set of all functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\mathbb{Z}: \mathbb{Z}^{\{1,2,3\}}$

$$|\mathbb{Z}^{\{1,2,3\}}|=\aleph_0^3=\aleph_0$$